# Export glTF with armature

Tags: armature, export, unreal-engine, gltf

I'm trying to export my model with aramature, but for some reason, I can't. When I export it and then reimport it to blender, I get only empties as a bones. If I try to import to Unreal, no armature at all. Am I exporting is somehow wrong?

Edit:
using blender 2.91.0
Mesh is parented to the bone and export works fine with fbx ( I can see the bone structure and bones are connected to the meshes)

Comment: Do you have a mesh with an Armature modifier? Is "Skinning" turned on in the export options?

Comment: Are you exporting .glb, .gltf or .gltf seperate?
In which Blender Version do you work?
Some else make sure Animation and skinning is selected in the export properties.

Comment: re "Mesh is parented to the bone". If you mean you do NOT have an armature modifier then you should know there is no distinction between "empties" and "bones" in glTF, and no notion of an "armature" at all. Unless a bone is used for skinning there will be no way to tell it _was_ a bone, rather than an empty, after export.

Comment: Ahaa, parenting is not enough. Is there tutorial how to do this export right?